# Preview of previous usage while locking the screen

Tags: firefox, lock-screen, privacy

When I am browsing on Firefox{installed through Mozilla's site}, I have (say) 2 tabs opened.
I am reading on the second tab. When I want to go away from my computer for a few minutes, I click Ctrl+Tab to go to the first tab. And then I press SUPER+L (to lock the screen).
But while the animation of "the curtain falling down" plays, the preview of the firefox window in the background shows the *full page of the second tab*. This happens even after I have *closed the second tab* before moving away!
I consider this as a privacy risk, because of some unexplainable circumstances.

**EDIT 7TH JULY**: Now I am experiencing the above problem across different apps too! Right now I was [fullscreen] on firefox, but app-2 was in the background[minimized MORE THAN 10 MINUTES AGO!]. But when I pressed Super+L, the preview of the app-2 along with the preview of the firefox tab (which I was on just before I had minimized the app-2) was shown, during the aforementioned animation. That is, the entire preview of my computer screen from more than 10 minutes ago was shown!